# Angle bisected in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image: The diagramme]

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $ID =JB$.

the point $P$ is the intersection of $DJ$ and $IB$.
Prove that the angle $X=Y$

$a,b,α,β$ are angles.

**What I realized:**

$a=b$.

and if we sum up these angles.
$$180=180-(x+α)+180-(y+β)+a $$
$$\iff 180=x+y+α+β-a \iff 360+2a=2(x+y)+2(α+β)$$

Please Help.

Comment: $2(x+y)=180^\circ$? Not really. Also: what's the source of the problem?

Comment: A math olympiad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend $CD$ to meet $BI$ in $Q$.

[image]

$$\triangle PJB \sim \triangle PDQ$$

Let $JB=x$ and $DQ=tx$, $t$ being the similarity ratio. So if $BP=y$, $PQ=ty$.

Let $CD=a=AB$. Now $\triangle IDQ \sim \triangle IAB$. So
$$\frac{ID}{DQ}=\frac{IA}{AB}\Rightarrow IA=a/t$$

$\therefore BC=AD=x+a/t$ and $CQ=tx+a$.

We see $$\frac{CQ}{BC}=t=\frac{PQ}{BP}\Rightarrow \angle PCD = \angle PCB$$

Answer (score 3):

It is straightforward by sine law,

$\angle PID = 180^0 - \beta, \angle PJB = 180^0 - \alpha, \angle DPI = \angle BPJ = \gamma$

So in $\triangle PID,  \frac{\sin \beta}{PD} = \frac{\sin \gamma}{ID}$

Similarly in $\triangle PBJ,  \frac{\sin \alpha}{PB} = \frac{\sin \gamma}{BJ}$

As $BJ = ID$, $ PD \sin \alpha = PB \sin \beta$

Now in $\triangle PCD,  \frac{\sin X}{PD} = \frac{\sin \alpha}{PC}$

In $\triangle PBC,  \frac{\sin Y}{PB} = \frac{\sin \beta}{PC}$

So, $\frac{\sin X}{\sin Y} = \frac{PD \sin \alpha}{PB \sin \beta} = 1$

$\therefore \angle X = \angle Y$

Comment: is there another method without using the sine law?